# Cannot select/get text from dynamic <li> items

Tags: jquery, dom, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js and have a drop down list of items that appears when the user begins typing in a search box (live filtering). Currently, the user can arrow through the list and hit enter to populate the search box.

> There is a live version in my [**personal site sandbox**](http://jonathonmoore.com/proto/).

However, I want the user to be able to scroll through the list as well and click on items. I can't quite figure out the location of these list items in the DOM because Knockout.js dynamically adds them in.

Here's the particular portion of code that is in question:

```
<div class="hidden" id='dropdown'>
    <ul id='dropdownList'
        data-bind="template: { name:'objects', foreach:obj }, 
                   click: function(){ $('#search').text(($(this).val());}">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is creating list items with the class of listObjItem, So could you do something like this.

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.listObjItem', function(){
       $('#search').val($(this).text());
   });
});
```

**EDIT**

To help clarify from comments below. Right now your code looks like this.

```
<ul id='dropdownList' data-bind="template: { name:'objects', foreach:obj }, 
            click: function(){ 
                $('.listObjItem').on('click', function(){
                        $('#search').val($(this).text())
                        $('#dropdown').hide();
                        $('#search').focus();
                    ;});
                }"></ul>
```

what I am saying to do is change the code to look like this.

```
 <ul id='dropdownList' data-bind="template: { name:'objects', foreach:obj }"></ul>
```

And add the following before the closing body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.listObjItem', function(){
       $('#search').val($(this).text());
       $('#dropdown').hide();
       $('#search').focus();
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That seemed to do it! Thanks, Blake.

Comment: Although it is worth noting that, for whatever reason, it seems to take two clicks to select it. Check it out: http://jonathonmoore.com/proto/. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984184/jquery-click-event-requires-two-clicks-to-fire). I think this is what is causing it.

Comment: @Jon If you initialize the .on(click) event in document.ready I think it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the click handler is the model data. Knockout provides the event object as the second parameter and you can then use `event.target`:

```
click: function(data,event){ $('#search').text(($(event.target).val());}
```